# Finding a specific string in an excel doc and printing the adjacent cell in powershell?

Tags: excel, powershell

Basically I have an excel document with 2 columns and a lot of rows. I am trying to figure out how to search the excel document for a string, and print the value next to it.

```
$strPath="G:\GNS\IP Information\New Techcare IP Spreadsheet.xlsx" 
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible=$false 
$WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath) 
$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Alhambra") 
$intRowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count $Columnnumber = 1 
$xl.Cells.Find("Gateway")
```

The last line is the one that finds the text I am looking for.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting an error we can help with? Maybe you should go search the internet for the Import-XLS script and try working with that.

Comment: I can import them and search just fine, what i am having trouble with is once i search for them, i either need to assign the cell location the a variable or the adjacent cell to a variable. thats what i need help doing.

Comment: show us the code you're working with to search with so we have some context to help you with.

Comment: $strPath="G:\GNS\IP Information\New Techcare IP Spreadsheet.xlsx"

$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$objExcel.Visible=$false

$WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)

$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Alhambra")

$intRowMax =  ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

$Columnnumber = 1

$xl.Cells.Find("Gateway") <--- Trying to get the cell location of this, so i can use that it the code

Comment: While I appreciate your quick response, edit your original question and put the code up there so that it can be formatted into an easily readable structure.

Comment: Try this: `$Searcher = $worksheet.usedrange.find("Gateway")` and see if $Searcher isn't the cell you are looking for. If it is, I'm pretty sure you can do `$Searcher.Offset(0,1)` to get the cell in the next column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just tested it as functional.

```
$Searcher = $worksheet.usedrange.find("Gateway")
$target = $Searcher.offset(0,1)
```

$target will be the cell that you are looking for. $target.value2 is the contents of that cell.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I needed. Still learning how to tie the functions together. It's so very different that any other coding/scripting language I've used.